# Why can't I see the URL website I run JavaFX web view?

Tags: java, javafx

When I run my code it should give me a GUI window with the oracle.com website inside. However, when I run the code I am just left with a blank screen. I have tried using different websites, but none have been successful. Also, I am running this code on a windows OS.

**Code:**

```
package sample;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import static javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;

public class Main extends Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage)
    {
        // Create the WebView
        WebView webView = new WebView();

        // Create the WebEngine
        final WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();

        // LOad the Start-Page
        webEngine.load("http://www.oracle.com");

        // Update the stage title when a new web page title is available
        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>()
        {
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State oldState, State newState)
            {
                if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED)
                {
                    //stage.setTitle(webEngine.getLocation());
                    stage.setTitle(webEngine.getTitle());
                }
            }
        });

        // Create the VBox
        VBox root = new VBox();
        // Add the WebView to the VBox
        root.getChildren().add(webView);

        // Set the Style-properties of the VBox
        root.setStyle("-fx-padding: 10;" +
                "-fx-border-style: solid inside;" +
                "-fx-border-width: 2;" +
                "-fx-border-insets: 5;" +
                "-fx-border-radius: 5;" +
                "-fx-border-color: blue;");

        // Create the Scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        // Add  the Scene to the Stage
        stage.setScene(scene);
        // Display the Stage
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me... (Also using windows and the latest version of JFX.)

Comment: I am working at a corporate office, do you think it has something to do with proxy? @MichaelBerry

Comment: Try observing the `Worker` for a `FAILED` state as well. If a `Worker` fails the reason will be in the `exception` property (of `Worker`).

Comment: @kane002 Yes, that's almost certainly the problem. Follow Slaw's advice to see what the issue might be.

Comment: I will look into it more,Thanks guys @Slaw